# Getting information for bins from the histogram function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am plotting a histogram in python using matplotlib by:

```py
plt.hist(nparray, bins=10, label='hist')
```

Is it possible to print a dataframe that has the information for all the bins, like number of elements in every bin?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The return values of [`plt.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)  are:

> Returns:   tuple : (n, bins, patches) or ([n0, n1, ...], bins,
>   [patches0, patches1,...])

So all you need to do is capture the return values appropriately.  For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some uniformly distributed data
x = np.random.rand(1000)

# create the histogram
(n, bins, patches) = plt.hist(x, bins=10, label='hst')

plt.show()

# inspect the counts in each bin
In [4]: print n
[102  87 102  83 106 100 104 110 102 104]

# and we see that the bins are approximately uniformly filled.
# create a second histogram with more bins (but same input data)
(n2, bins2, patches) = plt.hist(x, bins=20, label='hst')

In [34]: print n2
[54 48 39 48 51 51 37 46 49 57 50 50 52 52 59 51 58 44 58 46]

# bins are uniformly filled but obviously with fewer in each bin.
```

The `bins` that is returned defines the edges of each bin that was used.

Answer (score 0):

Binning values into discrete intervals in `plt.hist` is done using `np.histogram`, so if for some reason you want the bins and counts without plotting the data, you could use `np.histogram`. If you want the data together with the plot, as @Bonlenfum shows, the `hist()` call already returns such data.

As you can see from below, the counts and bins exactly match for pyplot and numpy histograms.

```py
x = np.random.rand(1000)
n_bins = 100

# plot histogram
n_plt, bins_plt, patches = plt.hist(x, n_bins)
# compute histogram
n_np, bins_np = np.histogram(x, n_bins)

(n_plt == n_np).all() and (bins_plt == bins_np).all()  # True
```